# unable to create new sandbox kindly help?

Tags: administration, sandbox

i am unable to create new sandbox kindly help ?
This is the steps i am following to set up a my first new sandbox

Administer Set UP >> Data management >> (no "Sandbox" available)

[image: No Sandbox option available in "data management tab"]

Comment: What Edition of Salesforce are you using?

Comment: Got the answer, i am using a free developer edition

Answer (score 1):

Are you in the production environment?  You can only see the sandboxes from production, so you would not see this link if you were in another sandbox.

Also, are you a system administrator?  If you are using a custom profile, you need to ensure that you have the 'View setup and configurations' and 'Modify all Data' permissions.

See documentation here
http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/data_sandbox_manage.htm

Answer (score 0):

Got the Answer

SANDBOXES ARE Available in: Enterprise, Unlimited, and Database.com Editions

As i am using developer edition, i don't have the "Sandbox" option.

[Sandboxes in detail study](http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/data_sandbox_manage.htm)

http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/data_sandbox_manage.htm